# Curtain up and down type animation to remove a view?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in which i want to include a curtain raiser type animation to remove my splash view from the window?can anybody help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create imageview, provide curtain type image to it and animate from bottom to top.